# Как наследовать класс typescript от класса javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Не получается реализовать такое:

```
class M extends HTMLElement
 {

 }
```

Существует ли вообще такая возможность? Спасибо.

Comment: `HTMLElement` - это не (совсем) класс. И такая запись в обычном яваскрипте [вполне сработала бы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements). Проблема в том, во что это компилирует компилятор typescript. Можно попробовать поставить в настройках компилятора target: es6 или как-то так

Comment: `HTMLElement` это интерфейст. Можно наследовать интерфейс от интерфейса. А клас должен реализовать

Comment: @НазарКалитюк, в яваскрипте все не так :-) имеется ввиду не тот `interface` который в других языках

Comment: Ок. ясно, спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

### данный вопрос относится чисто к JS - customelements

`target: es2015` +

https://learn.javascript.ru/webcomponent-core
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

```js
class customQwabrasComponent extends HTMLDivElement {
    constructor() {
        //@ts-ignore
        super(...arguments);
        this.props = {
            name: null
        };
        this.nameEl = document.createTextNode('anonymos');
        this.classList.add('fo');
        this.id = 'fo';
        this.style.color = 'red';
        // --
        this.innerHTML = `hello `;
        this.appendChild(this.nameEl);
        // --
        this.addEventListener('click', this)
        this.addEventListener('mouseout', this)
    }
    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['name'];
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(_key, _oldValue, _newValue) {
        console.log('attributeChangedCallback');
        if (_key in this.props)
            this.props[_key] = _newValue;
        this.render();
    }
    connectedCallback() { console.log('connectedCallback'); }
    handleEvent(_e) {
        console.log(`_e.type${_e.type}`);
    }
    render() {
        this.nameEl.textContent = this.props.name;
    }
}
customElements.define('custom-qwabras-component', customQwabrasComponent, { extends: 'div' });
let el = new customQwabrasComponent;
document.body.appendChild(el);
setTimeout(() => {
    el.setAttribute('name', 'qwabra');
}, 3e3);
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/document-register-element/1.8.0/document-register-element.js">/* W3C Custom Elements */</script>
```