# Как правильно исправить ошибку TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Всем привет! Никак не могу избавится от ошибки, очень прошу подсказать знающих. Вот модуль с ошибкой.

```
import Manager from './Manager';

// Тут получаю TS2351 : Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
const header = new (Manager.getHeader())();

// Можно решить так, но это костыль
const header = new (Manager.getHeader() as any)();
```

Модуль Manager

```
import DefaultHeader from './Headers/DefaultHeader/DefaultHeader';
import SwitchHeader from './Headers/SwitchHeader/SwitchHeader';
import TextHeader from './Headers/TextHeader/TextHeader';

// Какой тип нужно описать в возврате этой функции? Помогает typeof DefaultHeader, но есть ещё и TextHeader и другие?
function getHeader(name?: string): Function {
    switch (name) {
        case 'Text':
            return TextHeader;
        case 'Switch':
            return SwitchHeader;
        default:
            return DefaultHeader;
    }
}

export { getHeader, и много другого }
```

Сами Header представляют из себя классы с конструктором.

```
export default class DefaultHeader extends Header {
    constructor(params?: IHeaderConfig) {
        const conf: IHeaderConfig = {
            template
        };
        super(params, conf);
    }
}
```

Comment: чем собираешь, какая целевая версия JS

Comment: @qwabra Привет, gulp в es5. Проблему нужно искать со стороны сборки?

Comment: Предполагаю: "проблема" в несовместимости версий js - попробуй собрать под esnext/es6. Если заработает - думай и правь/создавай вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/822714/232932

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать что-то вроде [Type](https://angular.io/api/core/Type) разработанный разработчиками Angular.
Это синтаксис при котором ты четко указываешь, что возвращаемый тип содержит конструктор, который может быть вызван через new.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо. Поправил ответ в соответствии с вашими рекомендациями. Учту в следующих ответах. :)